# npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm facing an issue when I run the command ng new FirstAppAngular from the VSCode terminal in the directory PS D:>. The error occurs with Node.js version 20.9.0, npm version 10.2.4, and Angular version 17. Can you please assist me in resolving this problem?

````
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\othma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-22T16_43_04_058Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.```
````